# Writing URLs as a plain text to Excel in Python via XLSXwriter

Tags: python-2.7, xlsxwriter

Is it possible to write urls to .xlsx file via XLSXwriter as a plain text (without hyperlinks)?
I mean, when I write urls, they are inserted as visible part and hyperlink.
I would like to avoid hyperlink and leave url as a simple text string without any formatting

Here is my code:

```
b = xlsxwriter.Workbook(fn+'_'+time.strftime('%d.%m.%Y_%H-%M-%S')+'.xlsx')
s = b.add_worksheet()
s.set_zoom(125)
s.set_column('A:K', 30)
format = b.add_format({'align': 'left', 'font_name': 'Arial', 'font_size': 10})

s.write_row(0, 0, head, format)
for i in range(len(cols)):
    s.write_column(1, i, cols[i], format)

b.close()
```

thanks,

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You could use the `write_string()` method instead of `write_column()`. The `write_column()` method calls `write()` which calls `write_url()` by default. That would require you to roll your own loop.

[Or set the workbook constructor](http://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.org/workbook.html#constructor) property to tell the module to ignore urls when calling `write()`:

```
workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook(filename, {'strings_to_urls': False})
```

Comment: Thanks! And if you use pd.ExcelWriter you can use options={'strings_to_urls': False} for the constructor: https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/working_with_pandas.html?highlight=pd.ExcelWriter#passing-xlsxwriter-constructor-options-to-pandas